# Calculate weighted means for multiple grouping with different weightings in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, weighted-average

I've gone through the many posts on SO trying to get my code to work but still have some errors.  I'm trying to calculate weighted means for many columns based on different groupings. 
Specifically, I want to calculate the weighted mean of traits (in this case wingL, wingW, etc.) weighted by the value column.

Here is a sample dataset (because my matrix is HUGE) and some code:

```
>df
    year site  Species value  wingL  wingW   proL proW 
    2018    2    Aa      3.0   310.6  54.9   NA   1.1       
    2017    2    Aa      1.0   310.6  54.9   NA   1.1 
    2018    2    Bb      7.5    NA    20     3    1.0    
    2017    2    Bb      5      NA    20     3    1.0
    2018    4    Aa      8     310.6  54.9   NA   1.1       
    2017    4    Aa      6     310.6  54.9   NA   1.1
    2018    4    Cc      1    161.20   143.8  NA   NA 
    2017    4    Cc      1    161.20   143.8  NA   NA
    2018    6    Aa      12    310.6   54.9   NA   1.1  
    2018    6    Aa      9.5   310.6   54.9   NA   1.1
    2018    6    Cc      7    161.20   143.8  NA   NA 
    2017    6    Cc      7    161.20   143.8  NA   NA
```

Here is my code:

```
dfnew <- setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) weighted.mean(x, value)),
                       by = c("year", "Species"), .SDcols  = wingL:proW]
```

But all it does it delete the "value" column which is what I want to use as my weights. 
Basically, I want to calculate the weighted mean across rows for columns wingL:proW.  Then, once I have those data I eventually will average across  all species (Aa, Bb) at each site.

With code below I was able to correctly create a new df with just one new column (for wingL_wm) but can't figure out how to scale this for the many columns I have::

```
dfnew <- df %>% 
          group_by(year, site) %>%
          summarise(wingL_wm = weighted.mean(wingL, value))
```

Hope that makes sense. Thanks for the help
Here is a generic desired output though the "x" should be the calculated weighted means:

```
year site   wingL_WM  wingW_WM   proL_WM proW_WM
2018    2       x        x         x        x       
2017    2       x        x         x        x
2018    4       x        x         x        x
2017    4       x        x         x        x
2018    6       x        x         x        x    
2017    6       x        x         x        x
```

Comment: All but one of your groups have one row, so the weighted mean is just the value itself. Then for the one group which has > 1 row, all the values are the same so the weighted mean is just the repeated value. So the data.table code is taking a weighted mean by the groups you specified, it just might not look like it because that happens to be equivalent to just removing a few columns and rows for this data.

Comment: I'm confused and maybe explained wrong. I want to weight the traits (wingL for example) based on the value column - different per group. So for row 1 wingL= 310.6 should be weighted by 3.0 versus row 2 should be weighted by 1.0 since I am comparing years. These values will be averaged for each species per site.

Comment: Can you show the desired output? How many rows does the desired output have?

Comment: My matrix is huge (200 species, 75 sites, and about 100 traits) but I'll create a sample output which would be weighted means for each trait (averaged across species) per site.

Comment: Oh, if you just want to do it per site, your data.table code should work if you just modify the `by` argument to `by = Site`

Comment: To hop on IceCreamToucan's point, in your sample data, species `Aa` has three points in year `2018`, but every other row is uniquely identified by the year/species combination, so except for `2018/Aa` there is only a single value to average. If you throw `site` in the mix as well, then the only group with more than one row is `year:2018, site:6, species:Aa`. It's also confusing that in your `data.table` attempt you use `by = c("year", "Species")`, and in your `dplyr` attempt you use an additional grouper: `group_by(year, site, Species)`. What grouping do you actually want??

Comment: hhmmm. I have about 20 different species per each site. With different $values (to be used as the weight) for each site and year. Really, that is the only change between years.  So I want to calculate weighted average for each trait grouped by site and year .

Comment: Okay, so change your data.table code to `by = c("site", "year")` and you'll get 5 rows as sites 2 and 4 each have 2 years, and site 6 has one year. (prior to your data updates)

Comment: And if that's not what you want, then *please* edit the question to explicitly show the output that you do want, corrresponding to your sample input!

Comment: `dfnew <- setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) weighted.mean(x, value)), by = c("year", "site"), .SDcols  = wingL:proW]`  I think this is correct but it gives NAs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dfnew <- setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) weighted.mean(x, value, na.rm = TRUE)), by = c("year", "site"), .SDcols = wingL:proW]
```

I had to include the na.rm statement! I think this gives the correct results. Thanks everyone for helping me think it through as I did have errors by grouping - was over thinking it.

It does replace the original values, but I can live with that.